# Check network connection in background and upload data

Tags: ios

I get a requirement to be able to check if there is data with fail status and upload them via webservice.

The flow is gonna be:

> 1. User try to upload data but fail because of no internet connection
> 2. User stops using app, so the app goes background
> 3. Apps start to identify whether internet connection is available
> 4. If available, it directly calls web service to upload data
> 5. If not available, it will return to #3

Back to my last development on < iOS 7, previously background time was 10 minutes but becomes 3 minutes.

**Background Fetch**:

> When this method is called, your app has up to 30 seconds of
>   wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the
>   specified completion handler block. In practice, your app should call
>   the completion handler block as soon as possible after downloading the
>   needed data. If you do not call the completion handler in time, your
>   app is terminated.

Also that these are the only apps allowed to do background:

> 1. Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
> 2. Apps that record audio content while in the background.
> 3. Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
> 4. Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
> 5. Apps that need to download and process new content regularly (Background Fetch)
> 6. Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Isn't there any way I can do background in iOS yet or at least I can get the network status in background?

**Note:** My app is for internal distribution only, no need to worry with rejection.

Comment: I can help you with checking if your device have internet connection, this will run with your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is using `NSURLSession` instead of `NSURLConnection` (in case you are still using it)

**Difference between NSURLSession and NSURLConnection**

- NSURLConnection: if we have an open connection with NSURLConnection and the system interrupt our App, when our App goes to background mode, everything we have received or sent were lost.
  [image: Process diagram with NSURLConnection]
- NSURLSession: solve this problem and also give us out of process downloads. It manage the connection process even when we don't have access. You will need to use `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler` in your AppDelegate 
  [image: Process diagram with NSURLSession]

> So with the use of NSURLSession, you don't need to manage or to check
>   your internet connection because OS does it for you.

**Extra: How to check internet connection in my iOS app**

> Disclaimer: I'm not sure that the following Framework can run in background mode

You can use framework **Rechability** to check if your device have internet connection.

https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

It is a drop-in replacement for Apple's Reachability class and it supports blocks to perform action when you receive the NSNotification of reachability changed.

You can check the `README.md` at his repo but it is very simple to use.

**Using NSNotification**

***1***

In your *AppDelegate* you have to call

```
[Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
```

Also, you will need to declare a property to store that value

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Reachability *reach;
```

so now you will have to put the following code inside your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
_reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
```

***2***

In the Controller you need to check if reachability state, you must subscribe to that notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:_sharedInstance selector:@selector(reachabilityDidChange:) name:@"kReachabilityChanged" object:nil];
```

***3***

Now you can implement the selector `reachabilityDidChange:` where you check if now are connected or not. Put it in the same Controller.

```
- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    Reachability * reach = (Reachability *)[note object];

    if (self.appDelegate.wasConnected != [reach isReachable]){
        if ([reach isReachable]){
            NSLog(@"Notification Says Reachable");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ConnectionIsReachable" object:nil];
            [self sendPendingOperations];

        }else{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ConnectionIsUnreachable" object:nil];
            NSLog(@"Notification Says Unreachable");
        }

        self.appDelegate.wasConnected = [reach isReachable];
    }
}

As you can see, we store the last connection state also in a AppDelegate property

`@property BOOL wasConnected;`
```

***4***

Now you have to subscribe to those new notifications (`ConnectionIsReachable`, `ConnectionIsUnreachable`) and perform the action you need to do.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showNoConnectionAlert) name:@"ConnectionIsUnreachable" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideNoConnectionAlert) name:@"ConnectionIsReachable" object:nil];
```

**Using blocks**

I have not test it that feature but I copy to you the official documentation

```
// Allocate a reachability object
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

// Set the blocks
reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // keep in mind this is called on a background thread
    // and if you are updating the UI it needs to happen
    // on the main thread, like this:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSLog(@"REACHABLE!");
    });
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    NSLog(@"UNREACHABLE!");
};

// Start the notifier, which will cause the reachability object to retain itself!
[reach startNotifier];
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to understand more on NSURLSession and wrote another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423631/ios-background-execution after reading Apple's official doc. Thanks for Reachability reference, I will test it.