# iOS Background Execution

Tags: ios

I am trying to understand Apple's doc for Background Execution:

> Once configured, your NSURLSession object seamlessly hands off upload
>   and download tasks to the system at appropriate times. If tasks finish
>   while your app is still running (either in the foreground or the
>   background), the session object notifies its delegate in the usual
>   way. If tasks have not yet finished and the system terminates your
>   app, the system automatically continues managing the tasks in the
>   background. If the user terminates your app, the system cancels any
>   pending tasks.
>
> When all of the tasks associated with a background session are
>   complete, the system relaunches a terminated app (assuming that the
>   sessionSendsLaunchEvents property was set to YES and that the user did
>   not force quit the app) and calls the app delegate’s
>   application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:
>   method. (The system may also relaunch the app to handle authentication
>   challenges or other task-related events that require your app’s
>   attention.) In your implementation of that delegate method, use the
>   provided identifier to create a new NSURLSessionConfiguration and
>   NSURLSession object with the same configuration as before. The system
>   reconnects your new session object to the previous tasks and reports
>   their status to the session object’s delegate.

If I use `NSURLSession`, so when app goes background when uploading process is still on going, the process won't be killed or died as long as the application isn't terminated by user (I assume this is by killing my app from app list) ?

Answer (score 3):

Read the text carefully. As all good documentation, it says very clearly what it means, and you just need to read it carefully.

You didn't read it carefully.

There are three cases: Your app is still running when a task finishes, your app has been shut down by the system when the last task finishes, or the user has closed down the app before the last task finishes. No, it doesn't say anywhere that the app is kept alive. And the documentation says clearly what happens in each case.

iOS kills apps that are in the background and makes it look to the user as if they are still running.