# Is it possible to initiate an upload when app is suspended?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

Here is the user experience I am hoping to achieve: In my app user can take some photos and upload them to Amazon S3. It is likely that user won't have internet available at that time (nature of app and target market). So I want to store those photos in device if internet is not available and automatically start uploading them whenever internet is available.
And this is where I need help: How can I achieve this? If not completely, how much closer can I get to this user experience? Like stores the photos and start uploading when users opens the app next time or show a notification when internet is available, then user can tap on it to open app and start uploading etc.
Additional information: Each upload will take ~1 minute to complete. After an upload is complete I also need to make an http request (if that matters).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check network connection in background and upload data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393411/check-network-connection-in-background-and-upload-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Look into [`URLSessionUploadTask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession):

> *Upload tasks* are similar to data tasks, but they also send data (often in the form of a file), and support background uploads while
>   the app is not running.